# How to filter data from array in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, react-redux

```
let ing = this.state.getData.menus.map((item) => {
    return item.ingredients.filter((i) => {
        i.ingredient_name.includes(text);
    });
});
console.log(ing);
```

trying to filter data from the array which consists of objects of the array.

Comment: Share the valid input and respective output for clarification.

Comment: and? what is it logging? what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Next time, please show a sample of the data you need to filter, that will help people to help you faster.

Now, for the answer. as I'm not sure the data model you have, so I'm probably off in my answer. But, this is what I came up with. I'm sure there might be a better way, but this solves the problem if you have multiple results.

```js
const search = 'onions';
const recipes = [{
    'recipe_name': 'pasta',
    'ingredients': [{
        'ingredient_name': 'garlic',
        'ingredient_qty': 1
      }, {
        'ingredient_name': 'pasta',
        'ingredient_qty': 200
      },
      {
        'ingredient_name': 'parmegan',
        'ingredient_qty': 50
      }
    ]

  },
  {
    'recipe_name': 'soup',
    'ingredients': [{
        'ingredient_name': 'potatos',
        'ingredient_qty': 2
      },
      {
        'ingredient_name': 'onions',
        'ingredient_qty': 0.5
      },
      {
        'ingredient_name': 'water',
        'ingredient_qty': 250
      }
    ]
  }
];



const ing = recipes.flatMap((x, i) => {
  const indexes = [];
  const temp = x.ingredients.filter((i => i.ingredient_name === search));
  if (temp.length > 0) {
    indexes.push(i)
  }
  return (
    indexes.flatMap(i => recipes[i])
  )
});
console.log(ing);
```